# Using a third party plugin with Yii

Tags: yii

i am using a third party plugin with yii, it provides chat functionality, it has its own DB and php files that provide the functionality,

now i am want to use it in the view, but the simple include statements are not working, do i need to convert it to yii or can i use it as is?

```
<?php

session_start();

// Load MySQL DB settings
include_once('config.inc.php');

$_SESSION['username'] = 'Currently logged in users's username from database';
$_SESSION['user_id'] = 'Currently logged in user's id';

?>

//That's it! To print online users, you need to do it like this:

<?php
$users = mysql_query("SELECT id,username FROM ".$sql_table_users." WHERE chat_status='online' AND id!='".$_SESSION['user_id']."'");
if(mysql_num_rows($users) > 0){
    while($user = mysql_fetch_assoc($users)){
        print '<a href="#" alt="'.$user['id'].'|'.$user['username'].'" class="chat_user">'.$user['username'].'</a><br />';
    }
}
?>
```

this is the interface plugin has provided for me. 
plugin location is /assets/plugin.

i cant use direct php query commands to another Database, which i want to keep seperate from mine, plus the js file that comes with the plugin calls the script with wrong URL parameters, so what is the best method to incorperate this into my yii app. thanks

Comment: its a simple php plugin, this is from the documentation, meaning it works simply by using this code and adding a db in a normal php application, i want to ask how should i add it to the yii app. specially in my layout view. in a way that i can use it without altering the plugin code.

Comment: A link to the plugin you're using would be helpful.  It's also not clear what's not working if you try to implement it as above - though the `include_once()` will likely fail due to path issues.  Show us what you've tried and what errors you're seeing.  You also state "i cant use direct php query commands to another Database" - I'm not sure why you can't?

Comment: thanks for the help, there was a path issue as u suggested, i added the script directly in the view, and changed its paths according to directory structure and it worked, but i am not still fully satisfied by implementation, and partially its the plugins fault since it doesnt use a proper OOP structure, its poorly written. not worth its price. thanks for your help.

Comment: i thought that calling a script that involves its own DB connection, will not be possible from Yii's point of view, but it didnt bother complaining :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a Yii extension that'll wrap your plugin.
Then in your view you'll have to call a widget that'll display your chat.

I think this is the best way to do it because using this all your call to the plugin will be performed with the yii strucutre and philosophy. Only your extension will be structured using the chat philosophy.

[Source about creating widgets](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/extension.create#widget)

Comment: that is what i thought at first, but since i am not experianced in creating extensions my self, it will take too long to get started with it. any shortcut for this thing?

Comment: Whitout knowing what is the chat plugin you want to work with, it's hard to help you!

Comment: well i changed the plugin script, and its paths, and it started working, but for the future i would like to make an extension of it, i checked out your link, it isn't much helpful for a begineer, can u suggest something that would show me by example all the steps involved so that i can get crackin!

Comment: What is you level with yii? If you are a beginer, first learn the Yii guide (read all the chapters) then have a look at the doc api and at the end you should observe how the other wrapping plugins are done. In all the extensions you can find one that is doing something pretty similirar to what you want to achieve (take a php extension and wrap it). Here is an example http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/mail